# Line breaker in Javascript documentation comment

Tags: javascript, comments

just a quick question. As shown in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-lake-jpw7sc?file=/src/index.mjs), I'm not able to add a new line in javascript documentation comment. Anyone know how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Probably because of the way codesandbox.io implemented the tooltip based on the documentation. You could drop a suggestion to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a blank line between the first and second lines

```
  /**
   * First line
   *
   * Second line
   */
```

Comment: Yup this works! Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

Add two space characters at the end of the first line.

It behaves like [Markdown](https://commonmark.org/help/tutorial/03-paragraphs.html#:%7E:text=A%20paragraph%20is%20consecutive%20lines,the%20end%20of%20the%20line.)

```
/**
 * First line  <-- two spaces
 * Second line
 */
```

You could also add a backslash to the end of the line

```
/**
 * First line\
 * Second line
 */
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but the above answer work! Thanks anyway